# awk running total count and sum

Tags: awk

Would like to know how to calculate 80%-20% rule contribution of vendors on daily basis.

Input.csv

```
Date,Region,Vendor,Amount
5-Apr-15,east,cc,50
5-Apr-15,east,dd,15
5-Apr-15,south,bb,15
5-Apr-15,south,aa,10
7-Apr-15,east,cc,123
7-Apr-15,south,bb,88
7-Apr-15,south,aa,40
7-Apr-15,west,ss,30
7-Apr-15,west,rr,20
```

In the above input, based on $1 field need to populate Running Sum of Amount then calculate percentage of Running Sum of Amount for the day

```
Date,Region,Vendor,Amount,RunningSum,%RunningSum
5-Apr-15,east,cc,50,50,56%   (RunningSum=50 , %RunningSum=50/90(Total Amount for the day) 
5-Apr-15,east,dd,15,65,72%   (RunningSum=50+15, %RunningSum=65/90)
5-Apr-15,south,bb,15,80,89%  (RunningSum=65+15, %RunningSum=80/90)
5-Apr-15,south,aa,10,90,100% (RunningSum=80+10, %RunningSum=90/90)
```

Once it is derived 80% or first hit of 80%above need to consider as 80% contribution remaining line items need to be consider as 20% contribution.

Expected Output:

```
Date,Countof80%Vendor, SumOf80%Vendor, Countof20%Vendor, SumOf20%Vendor
5-Apr-15,3,80,1,10
7-Apr-15,3,251,2,50
```

Any suggestions ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is relatively complicated to do in `awk`, but here goes.

```
awk -F , '{vals[$1,++nums[$1]]=$4}END{
    for(d in nums){
        tot=0
        for(i=1;i<=nums[d];i++)tot+=vals[d,i]
        n=0;s=0
        for(i=1;i<=nums[d];i++){
            n++;s+=vals[d,i]
            if(s>=tot*0.8){s80=s;n80=n;s=0;n=0}
        }
        printf("%s,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",d,n80,s80,n,s)
    }
}' vendors.txt
```

This creates independent lists of values for each date, and after collecting all the data loops trough those lists and figures out where the 80% point is.

This assumes that the file contains only data (no "Date,Region,Vender.." header). If you want a one-line version for copy and paste purposes, here it is:

```
awk -F , '{vals[$1,++nums[$1]]=$4}END{for(d in nums){tot=0;for(i=1;i<=nums[d];i++)tot+=vals[d,i];n=0;s=0;for(i=1;i<=nums[d];i++){n++;s+=vals[d,i];if(s>=tot*0.8){s80=s;n80=n;s=0;n=0}};printf("%s,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",d,n80,s80,n,s)}}' vendors.txt
```

Edit: If you want counts separately for each region, you just need to change the $1 part into $1","$2, to concatenate date and region:

```
awk -F , '{a=$1","$2;vals[a,++nums[a]]=$4}END{for(d in nums){tot=0;for(i=1;i<=nums[d];i++)tot+=vals[d,i];n=0;s=0;for(i=1;i<=nums[d];i++){n++;s+=vals[d,i];if(s>=tot*0.8){s80=s;n80=n;s=0;n=0}};printf("%s,%d,%d,%d,%d\n",d,n80,s80,n,s)}}' vendors.txt
```

To be honest, though, I'm a bit unclear about exactly what you're trying to measure with this. For example, the number of vendors that make up 80% of the sales is not uniquely defined - it depends on the order you sort them in. If you sort all the small sales first, you will get a larger number than if you sort the large sales first. If you don't sort them in any particular order, you will get something intermediate. If what you want is how many of the biggest vendors make up 80% of the sales, then you will need to sort the array before counting.

Comment: Thanks a ton - amaurea for the inputs , where to change the code if I need to segeregate Date($1) and  Region ($2) wise : 80% -20% rule like Output header Date, Region, Countof80%Vendor,SumOf80%Vendor,Countof20%Vendor,SumOf20%Vendor

Comment: Amaurea , I am trying to measure biggest vendors make up 80% of the sales by Date wise & Region wise , Hence I will sort the input details based on Date & Region to Highest to Lowest numbers before running the script , so that i can able to see how many vendors contributing 80% sale against each Date & region level

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR { tot[$1] += $NF; next }
FNR==1 { print $0, "RunningSum", "%RunningSum"; next }
{ sum[$1]+=$NF; print $0, sum[$1], int(0.5+sum[$1]*100/tot[$1])"%" }

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
Date,Region,Vendor,Amount,RunningSum,%RunningSum
5-Apr-15,east,cc,50,50,56%
5-Apr-15,east,dd,15,65,72%
5-Apr-15,south,bb,15,80,89%
5-Apr-15,south,aa,10,90,100%
7-Apr-15,east,cc,123,123,41%
7-Apr-15,south,bb,88,211,70%
7-Apr-15,south,aa,40,251,83%
7-Apr-15,west,ss,30,281,93%
7-Apr-15,west,rr,20,301,100%
```

I've provide the answer above for the first part of your question but I have no idea how the part starting from `Once it is derived 80%` relates to it. Is that something else you want output to a separate file given the same input? Appended to the above output? A different script? Something else?

Comment: Ed Morton, thanks for the inputs,  actually I want to check how many vendors are contributing 80% of business (or till first hit of 80%above) And 20% of business based on Amount field ( $4) .  First part of question explained that how I am calculating the 80% - 20% rule.  Yes want excepted output to a separate file given the same input not Appended to the above output

Comment: and do you REALLY want both tables output tor do you actually only want the final table output?

Comment: Ed Morton , want the final table output only

Answer (score 3):

Here's a awk script to do that as the dates change:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
    print "Date" OFS "Countof80%Vendor" OFS "SumOf80%Vendor" OFS "Countof20%Vendor" OFS "SumOf20%Vendor"
}

FNR==1 { next } # skip the header

last_1 != $1 && FNR > 2 {
    output( a, cnt, tot, last_1 )
    cnt = tot = 0
    delete( a )
}

{ tot += $4; a[++cnt] = tot; last_1 = $1 }

END { output( a, cnt, tot, last_1 ) }


func output( a, cnt, tot, last_date,                 perc80, i, runsum ) {
    perc80 = .8 * tot
    for(i=1; i<=cnt; i++) {
        runsum = a[i]
        if(runsum >= perc80) {
            print last_date OFS i OFS runsum OFS (cnt-i) OFS (tot-runsum)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the break-down:

- `BEGIN` - set `FS` and `OFS` to `,`, then print the header
- `FNR==1` - skip the header row
- `last_1 != $1 && FNR > 2` - whenever the `$1` field changes values, print out the running totals by calling the function `output`.  Afterwards, clear the `cnt`, `tot` variables and delete the array `a`.
- For every non-header row, sum `$4` in `tot`.  Then set `a[++cnt] = tot` to capture both the running total at an index of the number of elements read so far.  Lastly, reset the `last_1` variable to `$1` after all the other processing.
- `END` - catch the final date grouping and print it with `output`

As for the function `output`:

- `perc80` - calc the 80% mark of the `tot` value.
- Walk the `a` array elements using `i` and `cnt`.
- store the value of `a[i]` into `runsum` for clarity/to reduce `a[i]` calls
- `if(runsum >= perc80)` print an output line then break.

Running this script gives the following output:

```
Date,Countof80%Vendor,SumOf80%Vendor,Countof20%Vendor,SumOf20%Vendor
5-Apr-15,3,80,1,10
7-Apr-15,3,251,2,50
```

Comment: Thanks a ton - n0741337 for very good explanation , where to change the code if I need to segeregate Date($1) and  Region ($2) wise : 80% -20% rule like Output header Date, Region, Countof80%Vendor,SumOf80%Vendor,Countof20%Vendor,SumOf20%Vendor

Comment: If I understand you correctly, as long as the file is sorted by both `$1` and `$2`, you'd "just" change how `last_1` is tested and made.  For example, `last_1 != ($1 OFS $2)` .  `last_date` in `output` could be renamed to `last_date_region` and an extra column should be added to the header.