# awk running total count and sum (Cont)

Tags: awk

In continuation of previous post , how to calculate 80%-20% rule contribution of vendors on Daily basis ($1) AND Region ($1) wise.

The input file is alredy sorted based on Date & Region and Amount from highest to lowest

Input.csv

```
Date,Region,Vendor,Amount
5-Apr-15,east,aa,123
5-Apr-15,east,bb,50
5-Apr-15,east,cc,15
5-Apr-15,south,dd,88
5-Apr-15,south,ee,40
5-Apr-15,south,ff,15
5-Apr-15,south,gg,10
7-Apr-15,east,ii,90
7-Apr-15,east,jj,20
```

In the above input, based on Date($1) AND Region ($2) field need to populate Running Sum of Amount then calculate percentage of Running Sum of Amount for the day & Region

```
Date,Region,Vendor,Amount,RunningSum,%RunningSum
5-Apr-15,east,aa,123,123,65%
5-Apr-15,east,bb,50,173,92%
5-Apr-15,east,cc,15,188,100%

5-Apr-15,south,dd,88,88,58%
5-Apr-15,south,ee,40,128,84%
5-Apr-15,south,ff,15,143,93%
5-Apr-15,south,gg,10,153,100%

7-Apr-15,east,ii,90,90,82%
7-Apr-15,east,jj,20,110,100%
```

Once it is derived 80% or first hit of 80%above need to consider as 80% contribution remaining line items need to be consider as 20% contribution.

```
Date,Region,Countof80%Vendor, SumOf80%Vendor, Countof20%Vendor, SumOf20%Vendor
5-Apr-15,east,2,173,1,15
5-Apr-15,south,2,128,2,25
7-Apr-15,east,1,90,1,20
```

Comment: Do you mean [this previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567142/awk-running-total-count-and-sum)? Not all of us are following your story arc that closely.

Comment: No glenn jackman , this is new post only , i have mentioned that continuation of my previous post and different situation  so that this post will not be treated as "Duplicate Question"

Comment: Post what you have tried to solve this. You've been asking awk questions long enough that this particular challenge should not be beyond you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk script will help you do the first part, ask if you need clarification. Basically it stores the values in arrays and prints out the requested info after parsing the document.

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}
    NR==1{print $0, "RunningSum", "%RunningSum"}
    NR!=1{  
        if (date == $1 && region == $2) {
            counts[i]++
            cities[i][counts[i]] = $3
            amounts[i][counts[i]] = $4
            rsum[i][counts[i]] = rsum[i][counts[i] - 1] + $4
        } else {
            date = $1; region = $2
            dates[++i] = $1 
            regions[i] = $2
            counts[i] = 1
            cities[i][1] = $3
            amounts[i][1] = $4
            rsum[i][1] = $4
        }
    }
    END{
        for(j=1; j<=i; j++) {
            total = rsum[j][counts[j]];
            for (k=1; k<=counts[j]; k++) {
                print dates[j], regions[j], cities[j][k], amounts[j][k], rsum[j][k], int(rsum[j][k]/total*100) "%"
            }
            if (j != i) { print "" }
        }
    }' yourfilename
```

The second part can be done like this (using the output of the first awk script):

```
awk -F'[,%]' 'BEGIN{ OFS="," }
    NR==1 || $0 ~ /^$/ {
        over = ""
        record = 1
    }
    ! (NR==1 || $0 ~ /^$/) {
        if (record) {
            dates[++i] = $1
            regions[i] = $2
            record = ""
        }
        if (over) {
            twenty[i]++
            twenties[i] += $4
        } else {
            eighty[i]++
            eighties[i] += $4
        }
        if ($6 >= 80) {
            over = 1
        }
    }
    END {
        print "Date","Region","Countof80%Vendor", "SumOf80%Vendor", "Countof20%Vendor", "SumOf20%Vendor"
        for (j=1; j<=i; j++) {
            print dates[j], regions[j], eighty[j], eighties[j], twenty[j], twenties[j]
        }
    }' output/file/of/first/script
```